# Server Error on Deploying Node.JS using Railway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment

I'm a novice coder and I just newly started learning deploying a simple web application over Railway. However I run into the server error message and I can't seem to know why.

I consulted their help page and I put in this code for the port, but it didn't work

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function () {
    console.log("Started on port 0.0.0.0")
  });
```

I also added this "start" line to my package.json under scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
    "start": "node main.js"
  },
```

This is the organization of files in my code editor
[image]